# Join tables using FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a line .kml which is needed to converted to shape. And I need to make a relation between "Folder" and "Placemark". I have a common field (kml_id in "Folder" and kml_parent in Placemark). How can I join them ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using the [FeatureMerger](https://www.safe.com/transformers/feature-merger/). Connect Placemark to the Requestor inputport and Folder to the Supplier inputport.

(In general you want the features with geometry as Requestor and the features with additional attributes as Supplier.)

[image]

Set "kml_parent" as Requestor and "kml_id" as Supplier.

(By default, these attributes are hidden / unexposed. You can unhide and use these attributes by clicking the cogwheel of the Feature Type, go to the tab Format Attributes and check the wanted attributes.)

[image]